How to iterate a Windows FileSystemObject of type Collection with javascript without using Enumerate
I'm forced to use JavaScript for an implementation, and for such implementation I need to list the files of a directory.
At first, it seems easy since we can get the following code from the Microsoft documentation:
var FSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

// Reference the Text directory
var Folder = FSO.GetFolder("c:\\Text");

// Reference the File collection of the Text directory
 var FileCollection = Folder.Files;

Response.Write("JScript Method<BR>");

// Display the number of files within the Text directory
Response.Write("Number of files found: " + FileCollection.Count + "<BR>");

// Traverse through the FileCollection using the FOR loop
for(var objEnum = new Enumerator(FileCollection); !objEnum.atEnd(); objEnum.moveNext()) {
 strFileName = objEnum.item();
 Response.Write(strFileName + "<BR>");
}

// Destroy and de-reference enumerator object
delete objEnum;
objEnum = null;

// De-reference FileCollection and Folder object
FileCollection = null;
Folder = null;

// Destroy and de-reference FileSystemObject
delete FSO;
FSO = null;

Code source: Microsoft documentation
But actually the JavaScript that I'm using do not has the Enumerator class. Is there any way to iterate such object without it?
Thank you,

Try the spread operator (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) - no idea if it fits, just something to try

@fdomn-m sadly I doesn't have such syntax either expected expression, got '...' :/

What environment are you running the js within?

@fdomn-m it seems to be SpiderMonkey 1.8, which implements Javascript 1.8
